# Pane output not updating

Tags: java, javafx, histogram, pane

I have the code to bubblesort an array of 20 integers and output the display as a bar graph that changes as its sorted.  My issue is that the graph never changes.  I used a println to verify that the code is going to the place where its supposed to output the bars, but nothing changes on my pane.  I've tried to use super.getChildren().removeAll(); and super.getChildren().clear(); before the bar output runs, but it still does not clear the pane.

```
package mp3;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Angel
 */
public class MP3 
extends Application 
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    throws Exception{
        Button bubble = new Button();
        bubble.setText("Bubble Sort");

        HBox hb = new HBox();
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        hb.getChildren().add(bubble);

        Histogram bars = new Histogram(); 
        root.getChildren().addAll( bars, hb);
        bars.setArray();
        BubbleSort bs = new BubbleSort(bars);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread (bs);

        bubble.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
        {
            thread1.start();
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Histogram");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}


package mp3;


import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

/** @author Angel */

public class Histogram 
extends Pane
{
    int[] numbers;
    int[] coloredIndexes;

    public void setNumbers (int[] nums)
    {
        numbers = nums;
        //System.out.println("call to set numbers");
        paintHistogram();
    }
    public void setNumbers (int[] nums, int[] indexes)
    {
        numbers = nums;
        coloredIndexes = indexes;
        paintHistogram();
    }
    public int[] getArray()
    {
        return numbers;
    }
    public void setArray()
    {
        int[] ar = new int[20];
        int[] ind = new int[20];
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = i;
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            int a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
        setNumbers(ar);
        paintHistogram();
    }

    public void paintHistogram()
    {

        System.out.println("in painting");
        int maxNumberOfArray = numbers[0];
        //max number in array
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > maxNumberOfArray)
                maxNumberOfArray = numbers[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        {
            int heightRectangle = numbers[i] * 5; 
            int widthRectangle = 5;
            int pos = 200-heightRectangle;
            Rectangle x = new Rectangle(i*10, pos, widthRectangle, heightRectangle);
            x.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            x.setFill(Color.MAGENTA);
            super.getChildren().add(x);
        }
    }
}


package mp3;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/** @author Angel */

public class BubbleSort 
extends Histogram
implements Runnable
{
    int[] sorting;
    Histogram sort;


    public BubbleSort(Histogram bars)
    {
        sorting = bars.getArray().clone();
        sort = bars;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        Platform.runLater(()->
        {
        int temp;
        //System.out.println("called run");
        for(int j = 0; j < sorting.length; ++j)
        {
        for(int i = 1; i < sorting.length; ++i)
        {
            //System.out.println("in sort loop");
            if(sorting[i - 1] > sorting[i])
            {
                    temp = sorting[i - 1];
                    sorting[i - 1] = sorting[i];
                    sorting[i] = temp;
                    //System.out.println("i: " + sorting[i] + "  i - 1: " + sorting[i - 1]);

                    setNumbers(sorting);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
             catch( InterruptedException e )
            {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            } 
            }
        }
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < sorting.length; ++k)
        {
            System.out.print(sorting[k] + ", ");
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried removing my button and letting the thread run alone with the only thing in the scene being the pane but as that runs the pane is blank and at the end it only shows the unsorted "chart"

Comment: You are running the entire sort on the FX Application Thread, so the FX Application Thread will not get an opportunity to update the UI until the whole thing is complete. Run the sort, and in particular the 50ms pauses, on the background thread, and just schedule the changes to the UI on the FX Application Thread.